# How can I use the intersects function for collision in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I am trying to make collisions for my platformer game in SFML, I saw somewhere that you can use `sprite.getBounds().intersects()` for collision, but I'm not sure what exactly to do afterwards. I didn't try to do anything yet.

Here's my code:

```cpp
    int main()
    {
        // Variables
    
    
        RenderWindow window(VideoMode(900, 900), "Daisy the Frog", Style::Close | Style::Titlebar);
        float dt;
        Clock clock;
    
    
    
        // Texture Variables
        Texture frogFront;
        Texture bg;
        Texture platform;
        Texture frogLeft;
        Texture frogLeftAnim;
        Sprite frogL;
        Sprite frogLA;
        Sprite frogF;
        Sprite bgs;
        Sprite platforms;
    
        // Code for the txts
        frogF.setPosition(Vector2f(200.f, 500.f));
        platforms.setScale(Vector2f(6.f, 4.5f));
        platforms.setPosition(Vector2f(0.f, 330.f));
        View view(FloatRect(200.f, 200.f, 300.f, 200.f));
    
        // Player config
        const float movementSpeed = 250.f;
        Vector2f velocity;
    
        if (!frogFront.loadFromFile("frog_front.png")) {
            cout << "Couldn't load texture" << endl;
    
        }
    
        if (!bg.loadFromFile("bg.png")) {
            cout << "Couldn't load texture" << endl;
    
        }
    
        if (!platform.loadFromFile("platform.png")) {
            cout << "Couldn't load texture" << endl;
        }
    
        if (!frogLeft.loadFromFile("frog_left.png")) {
            cout << "Couldn't load texture" << endl;
    
        }
    
        if (!frogLeftAnim.loadFromFile("frog_left_walkanim.png")) {
            cout << "Couldn't load texture" << endl;
    
        }
    
            bgs.setTexture(bg);
            frogF.setTexture(frogFront);
            platforms.setTexture(platform);
            frogL.setTexture(frogLeft);
            frogLA.setTexture(frogLeftAnim);
    
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            Event event;
            dt = clock.restart().asSeconds();
    
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                    window.close();
                }
            }
    
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    
            frogF.setScale(Vector2f(5.f, 5.f));
            bgs.setScale(Vector2f(7.24f, 7.24f));
    
            // Player config 2
            velocity.x = 0.f;
            velocity.y = 0.f;
    
    
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
                velocity.x += -movementSpeed * dt;
            } else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
                velocity.x += movementSpeed * dt;
            } else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space)) {
                velocity.y += -movementSpeed * dt;
    
            }
    
    
            frogF.move(velocity);
    
    
    
            window.draw(bgs);
            window.draw(platforms);
            window.draw(frogF);
    
            window.display();
    
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I need collisions with the player and the platform

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very interesting tutorial on designing a simple game that answers your question: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM92txFYjLI)

---

To solve your problem, you save the previous player position, and if the current position intersect with the obstacles, you change the player back to the previous one.

Comment: I tried implementing it, but I still can't. I mean that I can't find a way to apply this. Thanks for the response.

PS: I'm currently busy so I can't really reply as fast